# Unusual activity using .toggle to process function()

Tags: jquery

For some reason this code is working when i click on the #display div, instead of the #button div, why is it acting like this, it should be toggled when clicking on #button, not #display.. What am i doing wrong?

Here is the example code:

```
<script>

    $("#button").click( function(){ 

            $("#display").toggle(
                    function(){ alert('On') },
                    function(){ alert('Off') }
            );
     });

</script>
```

The HTML:

```
    <div id="button"></div>
    <div id="display"></div>
```

Here is an online example (working):
http://jsfiddle.net/MuMZV/

Comment: What does your CSS look like? I bet if you put a border on #button and #display it will give you some insight

Comment: wait actually you're using the wrong `.toggle()`: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ not http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: look here: http://jsfiddle.net/MuMZV/

Comment: Check this jsfiddle. No CSS.. http://jsfiddle.net/tcSWY/

Comment: Try also z-index:9999; on #button

Comment: @JustAnil, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you were passing into your toggle function were incorrect.  It's expecting, optionally, a duration, easing and callback.  Changing the code to:

```
$("#button1").click( function(){ 
   $("#display").toggle();
});
```

Causes clicks to your `button1` div to toggle the display of your `display` div.  And this:

```
$("#button1").click( function(){ 
   $("#display").toggle(2000, function() { alert("toggled"); });
});
```

Causes the hiding/slowing to slow to two seconds, with an alert popping up when finished.

And if you want to display true or false, based on whether the toggled element is visible, this is what you want:

```
$("#button1").click( function(){ 
   $("#display").toggle(1000, 
       function() { alert($(this).is(":visible")); });
});
```

Comment: so you can't use toggle (how i'm using it) to switch between 2 functions?

Comment: @ZeeTee - by my reading of the docs, I don't think so.  JustAnil's answer does get the functions to alternate, but it no longer toggles the display div, which I believe was part of your original requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing two functions in to `.toggle()`, so it's using the toggle-event method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

You probably want to pass in a duration and a callback, so you can use this method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

This is a really confusing thing for jQuery to do, to have two methods with the same name but wildly different results.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Maybe you should be more clear about what you expect to happen.

Comment: 2 different functions to be toggled, just like this.

Comment: I need you to tell me with complete sentences in excruciating detail what you want to happen, when it should happen, what should trigger it, using no pronouns. I don't know what you mean when you say "just like this". I can't see the hand gestures you're presumably making.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `toggle()` call with a `click` call? If you want it to toggle two functions when you click `#button` why did you type `$('#display').toggle`?

Comment: lol. Just would like to have a .toggle( function1, function2 )  and it toggle between the 2 functions.. I guess it's not possible? or i need to re-approach this from step 1.

Comment: #button.click() is binded to a function, the function is { .toggle(1,2) }

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
$('#button').toggle(function() {
    alert('First handler for .toggle() called.'); // On
}, function() {
    alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.'); // Off
});
```

With the same HTML:

```
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtCry/1/) : http://jsfiddle.net/mtCry/1/